How can I get write/wall commands working as intended?
OS: xUbuntu 22.04
I want to use the write / wall commands for sending msgs to other users sharing the same computer.
But when I try to use the write command, I get the following error:
√ ~ $ who
user1   tty7         2024-05-12 06:40 (:0)
user2  tty8         2024-05-13 06:56 (:1)
user3    tty9         2024-05-16 06:09 (:2)
user4    tty10        2024-05-16 11:54 (:3)
√ ~ $ write user2 tty8
write: effective gid does not match group of /dev/pts/13

The error is the same no matter what variation of the command I try: write user2, write user2 /dev/pts/13 or write user2 pts/13
I have been searching online and found just a few blurbs about the error. One such blurb seemed to suggest this behaviour was intentional, at least for Debian/buntu.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/2064685
I did try the advice in the link above to:

If you wish to restore the previous behavior, it should be sufficient to change /usr/bin/write.ul to root:tty 02755.

So that now my /etc/bin/write.ul has the setgid bit set:
√ ~ $ sudo chmod 02755 /usr/bin/write.ul
√ ~ $ ls /usr/bin/write.ul
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root root 23K Apr  9 10:32 /usr/bin/write.ul*

but doing so has made no change in the error received.
Any ideas what more I likely need to do to get these commands working as intended?

Just to chime in here for those running Debian with the relevant link: https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2024-28085

As per the advice you quote, you need to
sudo chown root:tty /usr/bin/write.ul

Your ls output shows that it is still owned by root:root.

P.S. You might need to do the chmod again after the chown.
